# Using Ajax to load beta signup page & clicking opt in without showing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to build a button that will allow users to automatically opt into all of a developer's beta apps (or the ones they select from a list I'll present) without the need to navigate to each beta app's sign-up page on the google playstore. I've tried the following, it loads the page, but I can't get the button-click/form submit right when trying it through ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.joaomgcd.autoshare',
  success: function( data ) {
    // process data (which is actually your page contents)
    //console.log(data);
    alert("Loaded");
    //$("input.action").click();
    //var clickme = document.querySelector(".action");
    $('.joinForm').submit()
    //clickme.click();
    alert("Done");
  }
});
```

I get the first popup, but not the second one. This particular developer has each link on one page of their website, I'm just trying to make it easier for his communities to opt into all betas instead of one-by-one. What am I doing wrong in my above code? Do I need to be clicking the input button titled "Become a Tester" (class `input.action`) or submitting the form that contains that input button (form class `joinForm`)?

Per request: Code of the Beta Opt-In page
[image]

Error being thrown:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code from the page you are trying to run this against or a link to the page?

Comment: Do you mean the page I'm trying to load through ajax or the page that this would be running on? The page I'm trying to load through ajax is listed in the url field in the above code. https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.joaomgcd.autoshare that's one of the sample beta opt-in pages.

Comment: The url loaded through ajax is not available to me or anyone else who is not part of the "testing program."

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't realize that. One sec

Comment: I've added a screenshot of it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console when submitting the form or clicking the submit button?

Comment: I can't get the form to submit or the button to click. The errors vary since I've tried the commented code about in multiple ways. But, it's usually along the lines of the variable doesn't have an object, like it's not finding the object regardless of what I specify

Comment: @hopkins-matt I've added another screenshot of the error that occurs when I uncomment all of my current lines of code. Any ideas?

Comment: Line should be `var clickme = document.querySelector(".action")[0];` to fix that error, but I don't know that will fix the original issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133490/discussion-between-hopkins-matt-and-caffeinatedcoder).